# CENTOS7: Gnome Desktop for Pi2 (xorg-x11-server package Missing)

Tags: setup, noobs

It was recently announced support for GNOME 3.14 and KDE 4.14 desktop environments, X.Org Server 1.17 display server"

http://news.softpedia.com/news/centos-7-linux-officially-released-for-raspberry-pi-2-banana-pi-and-cubietruck-497891.shtml
(shows a desktop image)

But then I came by https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=55708 that says it is not in the build.

When I install all

I get

```
startx
xauth:  file /root/.serverauth.9555 does not exist

xinit: unable to run server "/usr/bin/X": No such file or directory
Use the -- option, or make sure that /usr/bin is in your path and
that "/usr/bin/X" is a program or a link to the right type of server
for your display.  Possible server names include:

Xorg        Common X server for most displays
Xvfb        Virtual frame buffer
Xfake       kdrive-based virtual frame buffer
Xnest       X server nested in a window on another X server
Xephyr      kdrive-based nested X server
Xvnc        X server accessed over VNC's RFB protocol
Xdmx        Distributed Multi-head X server
```

Attempt at install:

## Update PI

yum -y update

## Install GNOME

`yum groupinstall x11 legacy-x
 yum groupinstall "Desktop" "Desktop Platform" "X Window System" "Fonts"
 yum install xterm
 yum groupinstall gnome
 yum install xorg-x11-server*`

Still nothing file /usr/bin/X does not exist

```
(on PI)
yum search xorg-x11-server-Xorg
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Warning: No matches found for: xorg-x11-server-Xorg
No matches found


On 6.7 Centos x64 box install:
 yum search xorg-x11-server-Xorg
 xorg-x11-server-Xorg.x86_64 : Xorg X server
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the last comment in the CentOS forum thread you linked to? It's from the CentOS Arm32 maintainer Fabian Arrotin:

> At the moment, we just built "Minimal" images, as that was the first goal and lot of people wanted to run those in "appliance" mode.
>   While we have built almost the whole distro, some packages failed to build , and the "desktop" role was not tested for armhfp/armv7hl
>   If you're interested in having a look at this, and contribute, feel free to browse the build logs (http://armv7.dev.centos.org/report.html) and join the centos arm-dev list (https://lists.centos.org/mailman/listinfo/arm-dev)

So your options if you want X on CentOS for Raspberry Pi is to either wait or help the project.

You can find the actual X server here: http://armv7.dev.centos.org/repodir/c71511-pass-1/xorg-x11-server/1.17.2-10.el7/armv7hl/ but it depends on libGL and libgbm that are part of mesa, which in turn is listed among the non-built packages at http://armv7.dev.centos.org/report.html

Comment: The download URL to the development release is exactly the right direction I was looking for.  Thanks for providing clarity to the subject. Hope it will assist others too.